# Solve this equation with respect to $a,b,c,d,δ,r,λ$ for all $n≥2$

Tags: real-analysis

Solve this equation:
$$n^{a}-n^{b}+n^{c}+n^{d}δ-n^{r}λ-n^{s}λδ=0$$

with respect to $a,b,c,d,δ,r,λ$ for all $n≥2$.

Comment: Do you want to solve for $n$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: No, with respect to $a,b,c,d,δ,r,λ$ for all $n≥2$

Comment: If you fix $n$ and fix any six of the variables $a,b,c,d,\delta,r,\lambda$, it is then trivial to solve for the seventh variable since each variable occurs only once (it's easy to group terms to make this true for $\delta$ and $\lambda$). If you want to fix those seven variables and solve in closed form for $n$, then it's hopeless in general.

Comment: @GregMartin: Ok and thank you very much.